# How to output with abstract class

Tags: java, abstract, tostring

I'm new to inheritance and abstract classes.

For this example I'm designing a phone book that can have a person or a business. The person has a title, first name, last name, and a phone number. The business has a business name and a phone number.
I created an abstract class with abstract method getName
(This may sound really simplistic to you guys but please bear with me!)

```
public  abstract class PhoneBook {

private String phone;


public boolean setPhone(String p) //final
{
    boolean flag = false;
    if(p.length()!= 10)
    {
        flag = false;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < p.length(); i++)
    {
        if(Character.isDigit(p.charAt(i)))
        {
            phone = p;
            flag = true;
        }
    }
    return flag;
}

public abstract String getName();

}
```

My two subclasses are Person and Business. The person's getName method concatenates the title, f name, l name.
In the main I created a PhoneBook array (abstract array) that can hold both a person or a business.

I'm having difficulties with the output...how do I access getPhone (in the abstract class) to output it?

This is the main (I'm currently only working on the person part)

```
import javax.swing.*;
```

public class PhoneBookEntries {

```
public static final int MAX = 100;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    PhoneBook[] phone = new PhoneBook[100];
    int selection;
    int i = 0;

    do{
        selection = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Would you like to add a\n1.person\n2.business\nto the phone book?"));

    switch(selection)
    {
    case 1: phone[i]= fillPerson();
        break;
    case 2: fillBusiness();
        break;
    }

    }while(i < MAX && JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Add another entry to phone book?")==JOptionPane.YES_OPTION);

    //output
    String output;
    output = phone[i].getName();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, output);

}

private static PhoneBook fillPerson()
{
    Person someone = new Person();
    someone.setTitle(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your title\n(Mr., Mrs., Ms., or Dr.)"));
    someone.setFName(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the first name of the person: "));
    someone.setLName(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the last name of the person: "));
    while(!someone.setPhone(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your 10 digit phone number: ")))
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error. Please enter only 10 numerical values\n(examle: 7034567890");
    return someone;
}

private static void fillBusiness()
{

}
```

}

getName I can easily access because I have PhoneBook[]. I was thinking I need a toString in Person to mush everything together (the while name and the phone number) but then in the main I can't access that toString because I don't have a Person instantiated?
Sorry if this is confusing...I'm just typing out my (poor) train of thought...

Comment: why can't you do `this.getPhone()` in the abstract class?  Just define the method and property there, since both implementations have that property...

Comment: fwiw, you might want to change your abstract class name.  It doesn't represent a phone book; it represents an entry....

Answer (score 2):

You should always be able to call `toString()` on any object because this is a method defined on `java.lang.Object` which is the superclass of all other classes.

So if you override `toString()` on your `Person` class you shouldn't have any issues calling it from your Abstract class.

I'm not exactly sure by your question what you are looking to do but here is an example of the toString implementation for Person:

```
@Override
public String toString(){

    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    String NEW_LINE = System.getProperty("line.separator");

    result.append(this.getClass().getName() + " Object {" + NEW_LINE);
    result.append(" Title: " + getTitle() + NEW_LINE);
    result.append(" FName: " + getFName() + NEW_LINE);
    result.append(" LName" + getLName + NEW_LINE );
    result.append("}");

    return result.toString();
}
```

Comment: does this have anything to do with the question?

Answer (score 0):

you should add a `getPhone` method to your abstract class (or any common method for that matter, thats the whole point of interfaces/abstract classes)

```
public String getPhone(){
    return phone
}
```

and if you need some specific format for person or business phones overwrite that method (or make the getter abstract. It depends on your requirements, but i guess the plain old getter is ok)

Answer (score 0):

I think part of the problem might be conceptual -- let me ramble a bit about abstract classes and such.

The idea behind any class is to represent some part of your system -- something you would represent with a noun that is a part of the system you are writing.  You have good examples of this in 'Person' and 'Business'; there are other ways to do things in this kind of application, but this is a good start.

Another poster mentioned "Entry", which I think is a good candidate for an abstract class in this case --  one 'entry' in the phone book could either be a business or a person; so the phone book can be full of "entries", and each entry is either a business or a person.

When one class inherits from another, it is best if the 'sub class' - Business or Person here - is a special case of the base class - Entry in this case.

Methods defined on entry should reflect entries, and not depend on the specific class on that entry.  For instance, it would be a mistake to put a getFirstName() method in Entry unless that applied to every possible subclass of Entry.  Since we don't usually think of a business as having a first name, that's probably a method we would only find in Person.

So you can have methods in Entry that can, for instance, return information you need to display the entry.  You could have a method getDisplayName(); in Entry it is an empty method, just defining that it takes no parameters and returns a String, in Person it could put together last, first, middle, or whatever you wanted; in Business, it could get the business name instead.

One more point - you don't want to put anything in any of these classes that has to do with "output"; these are classes that hold 'business objects' of your application, you would have other ones that dealt with output in all its forms.  There's nothing wrong with System.out.println statements for debugging, of course.

Comment: Thanks rcook that was a nice explanation. That's exactly what I did for the getDisplayName part that you mentioned. If I could've given you an arrow up, I woulda